# What does the error mean when enable honoree in contribute I get an error CiviCRM 4.6.8

Tags: civicontribute, custom-fields, 4.6.8, honoree

CiviCRM 4.6.8: When I enable honoree in contribute (even with the default setting: Honor type: "In honor of", "in memory of " and Honoree profile: "Honoree Individual " ) I get a warning: 
"warning the selected profile is using a custom field which is not assigned to the 'Contribution' being configured"

What does that mean?

Oddly I can use the test-drive link but not the live link. 
I can disable the honoree section and it works too.

What do I do wrong?

I tried it on the demo site http://d45.demo.civicrm.org but it seem to work there. (different version)

Comment: just to clarify, if you disable the honoree section, the error does not display?     It would seem that you have a profile containing a custom field that has a restriction on the type of contribution type and that the contribution page uses a different contribution type.

Comment: if I disable the honoree section, the error still displays. The difference is that with the honoree DISabled the public page displays. If I include the honoree information, the page refuses to display. This is the case the the default profiles as well. Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 3):

This is quite complicated, but as @pkeogan explains above, it all comes down to your profile using a custom field. To see custom fields that are restricted to specific contribution types, go to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Custom Data. Then you can see the allowed types for each fieldset in the Type column. You need to locate the one that your Honouree profile uses, but which does NOT include your contribution type in the Type column. (If you're unsure, go to Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles, and see for the fields in your profile.) Then, on the page at Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Custom Data, click ”more” on the relevant row, and then ”Settings”. There, see for the label ”Used For” to choose the types you need.

To understand this better, read the pages [Creating Custom Fields](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/) and [Profiles](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/) in the CiviCRM documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If the error still displays, then you most likely have an issue with a custom field in your profile.   I think  you have a profile containing a custom field that has a restriction on the type of contribution type and that the contribution page uses a different contribution type.

Comment: I solved the part of displaying the page on the public website. Civi > Administer > Access control > Joomla Access control > Public, ‘CiviCRM: Profile Create’ and ‘CiviCRM Profile edit’  set to 'allow'. Logic in retrospective. I still get the error popup on the backside.

Comment: How can I see if 1) the field is a custom field. Does it state so in the GUI? 2) if that filed is allowed in the type of contribution?

Comment: edited for clarity: How can I see if: 1) the field is a custom field. Does it state so in the GUI? 2) if that field is allowed in the type of contribution?